# Using post instead of get in rest-api to be able to use '+' unescaped in regex

Tags: rest, post, get

In my rest-api, I am using regexes. For querying the server, I normally use GET. However, there is the regex situation. With nearly all characters (even those that normally have to be escaped, like '['), this works just fine when using it in the address line, however, with '+', it doesn't. I am thinking about using a POST request instead so I can just specify the regex the body and don't have to escape anything. However, officially, POST requests are only used when changing something. Would it be bad to use a POST request here? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be bad to use a POST request here?

If you can use a `GET` for a safe request, you should do that.

> With nearly all characters (even those that normally have to be escaped, like '['), this works just fine when using it in the address line, however, with '+', it doesn't.

`+` means something magic in an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string (see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942159/54734)); if you are using a decoding function to get the data out of your url, but are not encoding that data when you copy it into the url, then you aren't going to have a good time.

If your encoders and decoders are correctly balanced, using `GET` should not be a problem.

> Well, my 'encoder' in this case would be a human typing something into the address bar...

And that's *fine*, provided that you don't use a decoder to parse the information you get on the server end.  That may mean that you need to parse the path/query by hand, rather than using "standard" library calls to do it.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Well, my 'encoder' in this case would be a human typing something into the address bar... (This is not my decision, so I can't change that part). And they tend not to want to encode everything manually. That's why I thought about using a POST request (wait, is it even possible to enter a post request into the address bar?). But this feels really wrong.